# How to find the window name using firebug?

Tags: selenium, firebug, selenium-ide

I can get the window name through selenium IDE, but with the same name, i cant able to find through firebug. Is there anyother way to find the window name using firebug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Open `Console` tab in Firebug;
2. Execute `window.name` or `window.document.title`.